# Python interpolate to larger 1D array

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a 1D temperature array whose length is 109 elements.  I would like to compare this array to a longer 1D temperature array whose length is 400 elements.  Both arrays vary through space, and I assume that the endpoints of each array is at the same lat/lon.  I want to interpolate the shorter array such that it has the same number of elements as the longer array.  I've attempted to use the np.array function, but it doesn't work properly (I could very well be doing something incorrectly).  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use a spline to interpolate. Here is my solution

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 399, num=109)
x_new = np.linspace(0, 399)
y = ARRAY WITH 109 ELEMENTS


def f(t):
    return interp.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
new_array = f(x_new)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!